Extract JOIN conditions from SQL using Antlr4 and Python
I would like to use Antrl4 in Python to process SQL/PLSQL scripts and extract JOIN conditions.
In order to do I am trying, first, to understand how these are represented in the parser tree returned by PlSqlParser.sql_script.
I have a simple SQL:
SELECT ta.col1, tb.col5
FROM   mytabA ta
JOIN  mayTabB tb ON ta.col1 = tb.col2
WHERE ta.col3 = 'AXA';

I use the following Python script to process the SQL script:
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.tree.Tree import TerminalNodeImpl
#from antlr4.tree.Tree import ParseTree
from antlr4.tree.Trees import Trees
from PlSqlLexer import PlSqlLexer
from PlSqlParser import PlSqlParser
from PlSqlParserListener import PlSqlParserListener


def handleTree(tree, lvl=0):
    for child in tree.getChildren():
        if isinstance(child, TerminalNode):
            print(lvl*'│ ' + '└─', child)
        else:
            handleTree(child, lvl+1)


class KeyPrinter(PlSqlParserListener):
    def enterSelect_statement(self, ctx):
        handleTree(ctx, 0)

def main():

        with open( "myscript.sql" ) as file:

            filesrc = file.read()

            lexer = PlSqlLexer(InputStream(filesrc))
            tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
            tokens.fill()
            parser = PlSqlParser(tokens)
            tree = parser.sql_script()

            printer = KeyPrinter()
            walker = ParseTreeWalker()
            walker.walk(printer, tree)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


And the output is:
│ │ │ │ └─ SELECT
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ ta
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ .
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ col1
│ │ │ │ │ └─ ,
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ tb
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ .
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ col5
│ │ │ │ │ └─ FROM
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ mytabA
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ ta
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ JOIN
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ mayTabB
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ tb
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ ON
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ ta
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ .
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ col1
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ =
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ tb
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ .
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ col2
│ │ │ │ │ └─ WHERE
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ ta
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ .
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ col3
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ =
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ 'AXA'


I change the handleTree function to print the child, to try and understand what info can be used to extract the information I am after:
def handleTree(tree, lvl=0):
    for child in tree.getChildren():
        print ( child )
        if isinstance(child, TerminalNode):
            print(lvl*'│ ' + '└─', child)
        else:
            handleTree(child, lvl+1)

The output now is:
[16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
SELECT
│ │ │ │ └─ SELECT
[16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19747 19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 19747 19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
ta
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ ta
.
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ .
[19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19747 19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 19747 19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16309 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
col1
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ col1
,
│ │ │ │ │ └─ ,
[16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19747 19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 19747 19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
tb
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ tb
.
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ .
[19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19747 19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 19747 19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17318 17280 17264 17255 16326 16311 16284 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
col5
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ col5
[16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
FROM
│ │ │ │ │ └─ FROM
[16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16351 16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16361 16351 16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17152 16361 16351 16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19376 17152 16361 16351 16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20207 19376 17152 16361 16351 16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 20207 19376 17152 16361 16351 16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
mytabA
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ mytabA
[16358 16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19174 16358 16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20207 19174 16358 16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 20207 19174 16358 16340 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
ta
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ ta
[16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
JOIN
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ JOIN
[16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16351 16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[16361 16351 16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17152 16361 16351 16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19376 17152 16361 16351 16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20207 19376 17152 16361 16351 16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 20207 19376 17152 16361 16351 16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
mayTabB
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ mayTabB
[16358 16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19174 16358 16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20207 19174 16358 16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 20207 19174 16358 16397 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
tb
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ tb
[16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
ON
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ ON
[16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19747 19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 19747 19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
ta
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ ta
.
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ .
[19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19747 19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 19747 19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
col1
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ col1
[17342 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
=
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ =
[17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19747 19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 19747 19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
tb
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ tb
.
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ .
[19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19747 19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 19747 19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 16414 16401 16341 16332 16320 16288 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
col2
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ col2
[16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
WHERE
│ │ │ │ │ └─ WHERE
[19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19747 19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 19747 19724 2342 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
ta
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ ta
.
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ .
[19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[19747 19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20209 19747 19733 17669 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 2070 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
col3
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ col3
[17342 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
=
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ =
[17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[17667 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
[20185 17667 17555 17472 17409 17350 17339 17343 17318 17280 17264 17255 17217 19182 16289 16263 16256 16066 16068 15857 2535 2384]
'AXA'
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ 'AXA'

It seems what I need to do is keep track of the child array values and identify which one(s) signal a table name, column name, JOIN etc.
Is using Antlr meant to be this complicated?
Is there a way to 'query' the tree structure for particular nodes, and if so what query to get this specific info?
Is there a way to print out the unique node types, such that we can figure out which ones to search for?

Do you need to do this with Python3, or can it be implemented using CSharp (much faster)? And, do you need for this to be implemented as an Antlr Visitor, or can it be implemented using a command-line program? You can still use Antlr, but writing programs to extract this is old fashion.

@kaby76  Python is being used because on a Linux system it's just more convenient to set up and use. Also, I've done a lot of work struggling to get the Pythion Antlr4 components set up and working, I'd rather not repeat that. I do not have a strong preference for using Visitors - my research led me to believe Visitor/Listener would be easiest way.  I suppose with C# I could used dotNet for Linux. Any practical suggests and help would be warmly appreciated.

@kaby76 to add as well, I managed to write a Python script that scanned through all the PLSQL code and extracts out each function/procedure, and any functions/procedures they call into a JSON file. I ended doing that by getting a flat tokenised source in a single string of numbers for tokens and names (like those in the question), and then some very ugly re.sub to whittle it down to the required data. That is slow -  took 40 minutes to process 400 files). So anything quicker would be considered.

The Python3 target is very slow because the plsql grammar is ambiguous. The CSharp target will be about ~8x's faster, a little faster. Will something like this work? $ trparse -i "SELECT ta.col1, tb.col5 FROM   mytabA ta JOIN  mayTabB tb ON ta.col1 = tb.col2 WHERE ta.col3 = 'AXA';" | trxgrep ' //join_clause' | trtext => JOIN  mayTabB tb ON ta.col1 = tb.col2

@kaby76 I am willing to give that a go, yes.

Here is a better way to print the parse tree to your console: https://gist.github.com/bkiers/13f72ef15d8353814cc7cbb93e9cc742

@BartKiers Thanks. This is a fantastic help. I'm still trying to figure out how such a structure can be 'queried' to easily pick out for example table names, column name from SQL.

Here's a quick demo how you could use a listener in Python to "listen" when the parser enters a tableview_name parser rule:
import antlr4
from PlSqlLexer import PlSqlLexer
from PlSqlParser import PlSqlParser
from antlr_utils import to_string_tree  # from: https://gist.github.com/bkiers/13f72ef15d8353814cc7cbb93e9cc742
from PlSqlParserListener import PlSqlParserListener


class TableViewListener(PlSqlParserListener):

    # (part of the) parse tree:
    #
    #    ║                    ║        ║  ║     ╚═ tableview_name
    #    ║                    ║        ║  ║        ╚═ identifier
    #    ║                    ║        ║  ║           ╚═ id_expression
    #    ║                    ║        ║  ║              ╚═ regular_id
    #    ║                    ║        ║  ║                 ╚═ "mytabA" (REGULAR_ID)
    #
    # ANTLR parser rule for `tableview_name`:
    #
    # tableview_name
    #     : identifier ('.' id_expression)? (
    #         AT_SIGN link_name
    #         | partition_extension_clause
    #     )?
    #     | xmltable outer_join_sign?
    #     ;
    def enterTableview_name(self, ctx:PlSqlParser.Tableview_nameContext):
        print('Found a table:', ctx.getText())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sql = """
        SELECT ta.col1, tb.col5
        FROM   mytabA ta
        JOIN  mayTabB tb ON ta.col1 = tb.col2
        WHERE ta.col3 = 'AXA';
        """
    lexer = PlSqlLexer(antlr4.InputStream(sql))
    parser = PlSqlParser(antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer))
    root = parser.sql_script()
    print(to_string_tree(root, lexer.symbolicNames))
    antlr4.ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(TableViewListener(), root)

Running the Python code above will print:
╚═ sql_script
   ╠═ unit_statement
   ║  ╚═ data_manipulation_language_statements
   ║     ╚═ select_statement
   ║        ╚═ select_only_statement
   ║           ╚═ subquery
   ║              ╚═ subquery_basic_elements
   ║                 ╚═ query_block
   ║                    ╠═ "SELECT" (SELECT)
   ║                    ╠═ selected_list
   ║                    ║  ╠═ select_list_elements
   ║                    ║  ║  ╚═ expression
   ║                    ║  ║     ╚═ logical_expression
   ║                    ║  ║        ╚═ unary_logical_expression
   ║                    ║  ║           ╚═ multiset_expression
   ║                    ║  ║              ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║  ║                 ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║  ║                    ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║  ║                       ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║  ║                          ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║  ║                             ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║  ║                                ╚═ general_element
   ║                    ║  ║                                   ╠═ general_element
   ║                    ║  ║                                   ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║  ║                                   ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║  ║                                   ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║  ║                                   ║           ╚═ "ta" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║  ║                                   ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                    ║  ║                                   ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║  ║                                      ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║  ║                                         ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║  ║                                            ╚═ "col1" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║  ╠═ "," (COMMA)
   ║                    ║  ╚═ select_list_elements
   ║                    ║     ╚═ expression
   ║                    ║        ╚═ logical_expression
   ║                    ║           ╚═ unary_logical_expression
   ║                    ║              ╚═ multiset_expression
   ║                    ║                 ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║                    ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║                       ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║                          ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║                             ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║                                ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║                                   ╚═ general_element
   ║                    ║                                      ╠═ general_element
   ║                    ║                                      ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║                                      ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║                                      ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║                                      ║           ╚═ "tb" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║                                      ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                    ║                                      ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║                                         ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║                                            ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║                                               ╚═ "col5" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ╠═ from_clause
   ║                    ║  ╠═ "FROM" (FROM)
   ║                    ║  ╚═ table_ref_list
   ║                    ║     ╚═ table_ref
   ║                    ║        ╠═ table_ref_aux
   ║                    ║        ║  ╠═ table_ref_aux_internal_one
   ║                    ║        ║  ║  ╚═ dml_table_expression_clause
   ║                    ║        ║  ║     ╚═ tableview_name
   ║                    ║        ║  ║        ╚═ identifier
   ║                    ║        ║  ║           ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║        ║  ║              ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║        ║  ║                 ╚═ "mytabA" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║        ║  ╚═ table_alias
   ║                    ║        ║     ╚═ identifier
   ║                    ║        ║        ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║        ║           ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║        ║              ╚═ "ta" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║        ╚═ join_clause
   ║                    ║           ╠═ "JOIN" (JOIN)
   ║                    ║           ╠═ table_ref_aux
   ║                    ║           ║  ╠═ table_ref_aux_internal_one
   ║                    ║           ║  ║  ╚═ dml_table_expression_clause
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ╚═ tableview_name
   ║                    ║           ║  ║        ╚═ identifier
   ║                    ║           ║  ║           ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║              ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║           ║  ║                 ╚═ "mayTabB" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║           ║  ╚═ table_alias
   ║                    ║           ║     ╚═ identifier
   ║                    ║           ║        ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║           ║           ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║           ║              ╚═ "tb" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║           ╚═ join_on_part
   ║                    ║              ╠═ "ON" (ON)
   ║                    ║              ╚═ condition
   ║                    ║                 ╚═ expression
   ║                    ║                    ╚═ logical_expression
   ║                    ║                       ╚═ unary_logical_expression
   ║                    ║                          ╚═ multiset_expression
   ║                    ║                             ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║                                ╠═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║  ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║     ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║                                ║        ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║           ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║              ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║                                ║                 ╚═ general_element
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ╠═ general_element
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ║           ╚═ "ta" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║                                ║                       ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║                          ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║                                ║                             ╚═ "col1" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║                                ╠═ relational_operator
   ║                    ║                                ║  ╚═ "=" (EQUALS_OP)
   ║                    ║                                ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║                                   ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║                                      ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║                                         ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║                                            ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║                                               ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║                                                  ╚═ general_element
   ║                    ║                                                     ╠═ general_element
   ║                    ║                                                     ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║                                                     ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║                                                     ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║                                                     ║           ╚═ "tb" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║                                                     ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                    ║                                                     ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║                                                        ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║                                                           ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║                                                              ╚═ "col2" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ╚═ where_clause
   ║                       ╠═ "WHERE" (WHERE)
   ║                       ╚═ condition
   ║                          ╚═ expression
   ║                             ╚═ logical_expression
   ║                                ╚═ unary_logical_expression
   ║                                   ╚═ multiset_expression
   ║                                      ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                                         ╠═ relational_expression
   ║                                         ║  ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                                         ║     ╚═ concatenation
   ║                                         ║        ╚═ model_expression
   ║                                         ║           ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                                         ║              ╚═ atom
   ║                                         ║                 ╚═ general_element
   ║                                         ║                    ╠═ general_element
   ║                                         ║                    ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                                         ║                    ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                                         ║                    ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                                         ║                    ║           ╚═ "ta" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                                         ║                    ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                                         ║                    ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                                         ║                       ╚═ id_expression
   ║                                         ║                          ╚═ regular_id
   ║                                         ║                             ╚═ "col3" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                                         ╠═ relational_operator
   ║                                         ║  ╚═ "=" (EQUALS_OP)
   ║                                         ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                                            ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                                               ╚═ concatenation
   ║                                                  ╚═ model_expression
   ║                                                     ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                                                        ╚═ atom
   ║                                                           ╚═ constant
   ║                                                              ╚═ quoted_string
   ║                                                                 ╚═ "'AXA'" (CHAR_STRING)
   ╠═ ";" (SEMICOLON)
   ╚═ "<EOF>"

Found a table: mytabA
Found a table: mayTabB

Notice the last 2 lines:
Found a table: mytabA
Found a table: mayTabB


Awesome. Exactly what I wanted, and I can build on this for other bits of info I want. Thank you.

There are many ways to solve the problem of extracting JOIN conditions from PlSql input files. The solution I suggest here uses Antlr4, [Dotnet] (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/), grammars-v4/sql/plsql grammar, and the Trash Toolkit, implementing a command-line approach. The solution involves generating a C# program for the grammar, running the program to create a parse tree, finding the parse tree nodes for the JOIN conditions, and printing out the results.
The advantage of this command-line solution is that you don't need to write a driver and visitor by hand. The generated code is a library that trparse uses to parse the input, then output fast, standardized parse trees, which is the lingua franca of the toolkit. The C# parser is about an order of magnitude faster than an equivalent Python3 parser.
Steps
I assume that you are using Ubuntu Linux and Bash.

Get prerequisites.
i) Install Dotnet 8. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu-install?pivots=os-linux-ubuntu-2404&tabs=dotnet8
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-8.0

ii) Install Trash Tool (only essential tools). See https://github.com/kaby76/Trash
 for t in trcaret trgen trglob triconv trparse trtext trwdog trxgrep trxml trxml2; do dotnet tool install -g $t; done


Clone the grammars-v4 repo, and navigate to the plsql grammar directory.
git clone https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4.git
cd grammars-v4/sql/plsql


Generate a C# parser program for the plsql grammar.
trgen -t CSharp
cd Generated-CSharp-full # (directory name varies)
make


Create input files (in.sql), parse input SQL files and extract JOIN. You can eliminate trparse output for errors and timing by redirecting to stderr.
$ trparse in.sql 2> /dev/null | trxgrep ' //join_clause' | trtext
JOIN  mayTabB tb ON ta.col1 = tb.col2
$ trparse -l in.sql 2> /dev/null | trxgrep ' //join_clause' | trcaret
L3: JOIN  mayTabB tb ON ta.col1 = tb.col2
    ^



trparse can parse multiple input files, e.g., trparse *.sql. trxgrep reads parse trees, and executes an XPath2 engine over the Antlr parse tree, and outputs parse trees satisfying the XPath expression. trtext reads parse trees and prints the text associated with each parse tree node. trcaret reads parse trees and outputs the line of text from the input containing the parse tree node, with a caret (requiring line information to be added in the parse trees via trparse). Using XPath, one can create complicated queries that relate different tree nodes, with certain values.

+10 Kaby thanks. I selected the other answer as the preferred one only because I think it will help me with the work I am doing using Python for this stuff. But I will also take a look at that trparse tool.
